# How to select first three rows after pagebreak ("^m")

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've tried to select first three rows after for each of page. It works fine only for first page. After first page I am finding manual page break ("^m") and try to select first three rows, but I got only two. Also this macros was written for Word 2007 and I try to rewrite to Word 2016

```
 Do While .Execute(FindText:="^m") = True
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
            Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord     
            headNumber = "2"
            lunghezza = 0
            cap = Selection.Text                                             
                    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                        Selection.TypeText Text:=headNumber                       
                        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
                        If Selection.Text <> vbCr Then                          
                           Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                           Selection.TypeParagraph                                                                             
                           Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
                        End If
                        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
                        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend                        
                        Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Custom Style " + NameOfStyle)
```

Comment: It's no problem to select the first 3 lines of each page.  What do you want to do with the selection?  I put in a stub of a routine just to demonstrate cycling through pages and selecting.  Let me know if this helps, or what you want to actually do with the selection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to select the first three lines of a document.  I would probably use Selection.GoTo for that instead of trying to find manual breaks.  I'm not clear what you want to do with the selection, so I'm going to put this stub of an answer in to show the page and line selection until I get some clarity on that.  I tested this with about 10 pages of random text using both natural and manual page breaks, with some cases of multiple consecutive manual page breaks.

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim p As Integer
    
    For p = 1 To ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, p
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
        Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've tried to put image instead of first three lines and I am getting wrong scenario. Attached image

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.  I don't see an image, either.

Comment: Sorry for this, I am trying to add Space Before for paragraph on the next page

Comment: I still don't quite understand.  You want to add a space before what?